# Chisel IO bundle that works for any width for a given Chisel hardware type

Tags: scala, generics, chisel, register-transfer-level

In chisel you can have a hardware generating function like the following:

```
def hw_func(x: Vec[UInt]) : Vec[UInt] = x  // useless I know
```

Where the formal argument and return value do not specify the width of the vector(s),
meaning the following is valid:

```
val x4 = Wire(Vec(6, UInt()))
val y4 = Wire(Vec(6, UInt()))

y4 := hw_func(y32)

val x32 = Wire(Vec(32, UInt()))
val y32 = Wire(Vec(32, UInt()))

y32 := hw_func(x32)
```

However say I have a Module class rather than a function:

```
class hw_module(widthX: Int, widthY: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO( new Bundle {
    val x = Input(Vec(widthX, UInt))
    val y = Input(Vec(widthY, UInt))
  })
  y := x
}
```

I have to use generics to parameterize the input and output, meaning when I instantiate the module class, I have to explicitly pass in width parameters, rather than having the compiler infer the widths as in the case of functions, like so:

```
val x4 = Wire(Vec(6, UInt()))
val y4 = Wire(Vec(6, UInt()))
val inst4 = hw_module(4, 4)

inst4.io.x := x4
y4 := inst4.io.y

val x32 = Wire(Vec(32, UInt()))
val y32 = Wire(Vec(32, UInt()))
val inst4 = hw_module(32, 32)

inst32.io.x := x32
y4 := inst32.io.y
```

Which is quite a bit more verbose (especially if say, I have a lot of i/o and they all potentially have different widths!).

Is there a way to achieve the inference of io widths seen in function hw generators with Module classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your issue. If you want to be able to receive a value `a` of type `A` and return a value `b` of type `B`, where `A` and `B` types can be anything, you can define a function like `def fromAToB[A,B](a: A): B = ...`. If that is not the case, please try to show what you expect to write and the expected behaviour. If you get an error from that, show the full error message.

Comment: my problem is one of clean/ maintainable code.

e.g.. In the case of a module with 20 Vec inputs, all of which could potentially have different widths, I don't want to have to declare 20 generic Int paramters for each of the input widths.

Comment: I don't have experience with Chisel. When you say "a module with 20 Vec inputs" l'm not sure what is that. Could you edit your post and show an example of code pointing what is what you would like to do with that?

Comment: second code snippet already shows this,

Imagine if new Bundle { ... } had a,b,c,d,e, ..., x,y,z Vecs and each of those need a separate generic arg for the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type parameter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html)([chisel-doc](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/polymorphism-and-parameterization.html)) to create a more generic modules or bundles

```scala
class Foo[T <: Data](gen: T) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val x = Input(gen)
    val y = Output(gen)
  })

  io.x <> io.y
}


class Bar extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val x1 = Input(Vec(6, UInt(32.W)))
    val x2 = Input(UInt(16.W))
    val x3 = Input(Bool())
    val y1 = Output(Vec(6, UInt(32.W)))
    val y2 = Output(UInt(16.W))
    val y3 = Output(Bool())
  })

  val foo1 = Module(new Foo(io.x1.cloneType))
  val foo2 = Module(new Foo(io.x2.cloneType))
  val foo3 = Module(new Foo(io.x3.cloneType))

  io.x1 <> foo1.io.x
  io.x2 <> foo2.io.x
  io.x3 <> foo3.io.x
  
  io.y1 <> foo1.io.y
  io.y2 <> foo2.io.y
  io.y3 <> foo3.io.y 
}
```